# Why does UIActivityIndicatorView only animate the first time it is visible?

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

I change the navigation bar title depending on the network status, when there is no connection I display as UIActivityIndicatorView, along side "Waiting for network".  This works perfectly the very first time I turn off network connectivity, when I disable it for the second time,  "Waiting for network" and the Activity indicator  appear, however, it doesn't animate.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        label.text = "Waiting for network"
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
        label.textColor = .black
        
     
        containerView.addSubview(self.activityIndicator)
        containerView.addSubview(label)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.activityIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.activityIndicator.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor),
            self.activityIndicator.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor),
            label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor),
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.activityIndicator.trailingAnchor, constant: 8),
            containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.widthAnchor, constant: self.activityIndicator.frame.width + 8)
        ])
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    
    
    func onUpdate(_ isConnected: Bool) {
        print("isInternetConnected changed to: \(isConnected)")

        if isConnected {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                
                self.navigationItem.titleView = nil
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                self.navigationItem.title = "Chats"
            }
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.navigationItem.titleView = 

self.containerView
 self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()


            }
        }
    } 

  let activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = {
        let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
        activityIndicator.style = .medium
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.color = .black
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        return activityIndicator
    }()
```

Comment: you need `self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()` in the else part...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start animation by calling `self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()`, as you stop it when `isConnected` is true

```
   if isConnected {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            
            self.navigationItem.titleView = nil
            if self.activityIndicator.isAnimating {
                 self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            }
            self.navigationItem.title = "Chats"
        }
    } else {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.navigationItem.titleView = self.containerView
            if !self.activityIndicator.isAnimating {
                 self.activityIndicator.startAnimating() // <<< --- here
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you I had tried that, the indicator did reappear, however, it was just static, and did not animate.

Comment: 1. don't run `startAnimation` multiple times. 2. no need to run `activityIndicator.startAnimating()` in `let activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView`. 3. be sure to call start/stop while the `activityIndicator` is still in view (also it's not clear that `containerView` is, because when you set `self.navigationItem.titleView = nil` your containerView loses its parentView and you will break your `NSLayoutConstraint`, that could also break animation -  try to initiate new View with label and indicator instead.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated! setting to nil was breaking it!